# PHPMailer for SMTP sends mail to inbox but from invalid mail address

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Need help!!!
I am using php mailer in my current project. It works successfully, after sending a mail successfully to the other end it says the mail comes from the smtp server account not from the $from what i use here-

```
$to ="muradautorun@gmail.com";
$from ="tanvir_cse0906@yahoo.com";
```

My smtp server code here..

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465; 


$mail->Username = "muradautorun"; 
$mail->Password = "";  //my passsword here
```

Here is my complete code-

```
    $to ="muradautorun@gmail.com";
    $from ="tanvir_cse0906@yahoo.com";
    $from_name="S.M. Murad Hasan Tanvir";
    $subject="A sending mail code";
    $body ="This is a sending email code, the file attach here is about the coding.";

    //here i use gmail as a smtp server
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465; 


    $mail->Username = "muradautorun"; 
    $mail->Password = "";  //my passsword here


    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->addAttachment('emailSend.php');         // Add attachment(just the file url)
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);


    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
    } 
    else {
        echo 'Message sent!';
    }
?>
```

Where i doing wrong i can't find out please help me...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow sending mail as "tanvir_cse0906@yahoo.com" on your "muradautorun" gmail account first.

You can do this by following the following steps:

1. Login with "muradautorun"
2. Click the gear in the top right and choose "Settings"
3. Click on the "Accounts and Import" tab
4. Click on link "Add another email address you own" in the "Send mail as" section, and follow the instructions.

Comment: Sir   
It is not a fixed email address.  It is dynamically change.
  If i set tanvir_cse0906@yahoo.com then what about the other email addresses?  Is it about to add all the eamil address into my muradautorun account??

Comment: @mpranks if this is your requirement, then you need to send using a different service other than gmail as that's simply how gmail works as a anti-fraud mechanism. You could send locally through your web server using sendmail if available.

Comment: Sir, Its not my requirement. Actually i don't know much about it or the mechanism.